# 404 Page not found error while trying to upload image in tinymce

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

While trying to upload the image in tinymce editor using filemanager plugin it shows 404 page not found error in Codeigniter.
It does not show any error in local and also in one of my domain. The problem occurred only while uploaded in client's domain.

What might be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Server API of my domain is "Apache 2.0 Handler" where as my client's is "CGI/FastCGI".

Comment: You may not be changed **baseurl** given in tiny mce js file